# How to open another app which is not installed on the user device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, automation, backend

I want to make a system in which user enters some details and it fetches the data from using services from some another app which might not be installed on the users mobile. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this using push notification.

1. You can post a request to the server with the device id or userid to push this request to other device
2. Server will use the FCM(Firebase cloud messaging) to push this request to the device to open the app

Comment: I want to run that other app in my own server. Like I want to make an app that fills the form of some other app. In this user will give the data through my app and it will automatically fill that data on some other app in backend and return to the user with their registration number. So how it can be achieved? I don't want the user to open or even required to have that another app installed on their device.